# How to retrieve values from dynamically created textboxes in wpf?

Tags: wpf, sqlite

The column names and their respective values are dynamically added by user. The user can edit those values. I managed to get the column names into labels and column values into textboxes. The textboxes are children of a stackpanel. Now I want to save the edited values (inside textbox, changed by user).

Here's my code:

```
             foreach (TextBox element in second_panel.Children)
             {
                    if (element.Name == column_name)
                    {
                        column_value = element.Text;
                        SQLiteCommand command3 = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
                        command3.CommandText = "update order_tb set @columnname = @columnvalue where Order_No = @orderno";
                        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnname", column_name);
                        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnvalue", column_value);
                        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderno", order_no);
                        command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

But I am getting this error -- System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error near "@columnname": syntax error'.

Any alternative method to achieve the result would do too.

Comment: I think the column name must be explicit. Not as a parameter. You don't need dynamic column names either.

Comment: You always update a concrete table and a concrete column or row of that table with variable values. So the values can be parameterized only. Otherwise syntax error.

Comment: But I need the columns to be dynamic. The user has to set those.

Comment: But you are thinking the wrong way. Why don't you create a column called user_column_name to store this value?

Comment: What is your goal maybe I can help you. But you definitly don't want the user to rename the database's column names.

Comment: The user is interested in the values in the database not in the database itself and how the tables and columns are named, right?

Comment: Right. What I did is whatever fields the user require, I created a table with those fields. Whenever the user wants to add a field or delete a field, I do those operations on the table. The user can add/update the values in that table. As the column names are dynamic, I am not able to query it with column names and the query is not accepting variables instead of column names.

Comment: It's done like this: the user wants to edit his name? Then you call a method `UpdateName(name)` which operates on the NAME column to alter its value. User adds a new product to his shopping cart? Then invoke a method `AddProduct(productId)` which eventually will create a new row in the table SHOPPING_CART. There is always a concrete operations mapped to a user's action or Use Case or User Story. Your code will also look better and  will become more maintainable.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to let the user decide which table column to update. That's why what you are trying to do is not possible. You as the programmer are responsible how the database or a table is structured and updated. You know where a certain value has to go. You always need to maintain the database's integrity. The user doesn't know anything about it. Each value maps to a concrete column, which means each user input (text box) maps to a concrete column. Nothing is dynamic regarding this mapping or your database would become useless. It's fixed from the moment you created the table.

Comment: "What I did is whatever fields the user require, I created a table with those fields. " What do you mean? When the user needs information about his purchase from a certain date, then you create a new table to contain this data? Are you sure?

Comment: You confused yourself. You fetch data from the USER table, let's say the PHONE_NUMBER column. You now map it to a text box which allows the user to edit it. When he is done you write the new value back to the PHONE_NUMBER column of the USER table. You know the table name and you now the column name. Where is the problem?

Comment: So, to update the phone number your parameterized query becomes: `UPDATE USER SET PHONE_NUMBER = @phoneNumber WHERE USER_ID = @userId`. This query is executed by the method called `UpdatePhoneNumber(long userId, long phoneNumber)`.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks. I really appreciate your help.